# When converting to unsigned, the standard says "the least unsigned integer" is the result. Why does "least" matter here?

Tags: c++

C++ standard says in [[conv.integral/2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#2), about integer conversion to unsigned:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the **least** unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup>
>    where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).

My question is, why the word "**least**" is there? Is it possible that multiple results are possible, and we need to choose one from them?

Comment: it wouldn't make much sense if `(unsigned int)-1` gave `35184372088831` would it?  (that number is congruent to -1 mod 2^32)

Comment: @M.M: sure. but that's an impossible value for an `unsigned int` anyway (supposing 32-bit `int`s)

Comment: The chosen wording seems simpler to me than "the resulting value is the unsigned integer congruent to the source integer which falls within the range of the destination type"

Comment: @M.M: okay :) For me, your wording is much better, because the intent is clearer. But maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are an infinite number of integers equal to any value k modulo 2<sup>n</sup>.  There is k, k+2<sup>n</sup>, k+2*2<sup>n</sup>, k+3*2<sup>n</sup>, k-2<sup>n</sup>, k-2*k<sup>n</sup>, etc.

Of these, one is the least unsigned (positive) value.

Parts of the C++ standard are specified in math.  I believe this is one of them.

Comment: Yes, but only `k` is the possible one, isn't it? All the other candidates are out of range.

Comment: @geza pass 500 to an unsigned 8 bit type, or -1 to any unsigned type.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I meant, that there is only one number, which could satisfy congruency, and is in range. Why would we need to say "least". But now I see that the authors of the standard don't have the "in range" requirement in mind. For me, it's just confusing, because I wouldn't consider out-of-range results by default.

Comment: @geza that is how they specify the range, in effect.